# Can I use custom image as map with Silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, dictionary

I have to develop a silverlight application which will run intranet.

It will show local town map and have some images over the map like pushpins. I can use Deep Zoom for map application. But adding images and events for images is not supported.

For silverlight 2, there is DeepEarth api for this. But How can I do this with Silverlight 3?

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight 3 is backwards compatible so DeepEarth should work in a Silverlight 3 application as far as I'm aware.